# upload files to another shared hosting, with django

Tags: python, django, upload, web-hosting, shared-hosting

i have a django shared hosting(cpanel), but for storaging files coming from Front-end, i needed more space so i got an another shared-hosting(direct-admin) to upload files there, i connected the shared-hosting-storage to django-shared-hosting as a sub domain(in capnel with ip in ZoneEditor), like: http://dl.sabaol.ir, but i dont know how to upload files with django from django-shared-hosting to my shared-hosting-storage coming from front-end,i hope u guys to understand what i said :/

and consider that shared-hosting-storage is only for storage, we cant publish backend, db ..., its just for storage, thats why its cheaper than normal shared-hosting,

i googled so much about that , some said use ftp, is it right? if it is, how?

Comment: You will need to implement an interface (your own API) to connect to that shared hosting storage from django.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18778381/) for how this might be done, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408200/how-to-store-image-files-in-django) for general overview on how this is typically done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, for uploading files to shared-hosting-storage automatically by django, we need ftp system , with django-storages package, we can do this easily,
go to this url and ftp tab,

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io